# Sort a json array in python that starts with an integer

Tags: php, python, mysql, database

I have a json file that looks like this::

```
 {
    "1": {
       "name": "item1"
       "symbol": "symbol1"
       "quotes": {
          "Amount": "45345"
          "other": "value"
         }
      }
   "734": {
     "name": "item1"
     "symbol": "symbol1"
     "quotes": {
        "Amount": "45345"
        "other": "value"
       }
    }
   "378": {
     "name": "item1"
     "symbol": "symbol1"
     "quotes": {
        "Amount": "45345"
        "other": "value"
        }
      }
   "2": {
     "name": "item1"
     "symbol": "symbol1"
     "quotes": {
        "Amount": "45345"
        "other": "value"
       }
      }
 }
```

The "type" where the number is placed is a string value. if that helps.

Normally someone is not trying to make extra work and label the "key" with the value of an integer...

I am trying to place this file and some other json into a mysql data base.

My research has taught me that this process will look ab bit like this::

```
    # !!!!!!!!!!This is a copy paste from another solution::::::!!!!!!!

    json_obj = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

    #print(json_obj["products"][0]["upc"])

    for product in json_obj["products"]:
        print("upc:", product["upc"])
        print("sku:", product["sku"])
        print("salePrice:", product["salePrice"])
        print('---')
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bestb (sku, upc, salePrice) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (product["sku"], product["upc"], product["salePrice"]))
```

The above states that we will load the json file and read it, while writing the keys to cols. -- Makes sense... how do I perfrom this process with a loop of my integers....

I started with a while loop

```
i = 1
while 1 < 400:
    print(data - to mysql)
```

I am using python to pull form the API, then "normalizing" the data to insert into mysql, there php will pull the data to some charts and graphs.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import json
json = {
    "1": {
       "name": "item1",
       "symbol": "symbol1",
       "quotes": {
          "Amount": "45345",
          "other": "value",
         }
      },
   "734": {
     "name": "item1",
     "symbol": "symbol1",
     "quotes": {
        "Amount": "45345",
        "other": "value",
       }
    },
   "378": {
     "name": "item1",
     "symbol": "symbol1",
     "quotes": {
        "Amount": "45345",
        "other": "value",
        }
      },
   "2": {
     "name": "item1",
     "symbol": "symbol1",
     "quotes": {
        "Amount": "45345",
        "other": "value",
       }
      }
 };


jsonSorted = sorted(json.items()) 

print(jsonSorted)
```

Comment: Super! that helps with sort... but the issue is calling all of the data objects into a my sql table where the string/integer value will be the ID. Then store the rest of the data object. 

The goal I guess is the loop code for storing the json into the MYSQL... because we don't have a "normal" array.

Comment: Do you need to cycle a json to insert column by column?